# How can I run a jQuery function only when it's needed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've run into a problem where I have a responsive slider running on my site which has been added to an external .js file. I am running into an issue with a modal not popping up on the homepage because the page is looking for the slider which is only included on a couple of sub pages.

Chrome console is showing the following error:
 `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`

Here is my current code:

```
$('.my-carousel').slick({
    speed: 330,
    slidesToShow: 4,
});
```

Comment: You would need to load the javascript (slick carousel for instance) in to any page you want to make use of it on. If the library is not loaded then the `.slick` property in this case will be undefined, hence the error you are seing.

Comment: Use *typeof* for this purpose: `if( typeof YourVar_orElement !== 'undefined' ) { // do work }`. Check [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/typeof).  *The typeof operator returns a string indicating the type of the unevaluated operand.*

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can check if plugin has been loaded like this (it checks if given jQuery function exists):

```
if ($().slick) {
 // .. your code
}
```

or

```
if ($.fn.slick) {
 // .. your code
}
```

Comment: Isn't it necessary to pass a selector to the `$()`?

Comment: I'd suggest `if ('slick' in $.fn && typeof $.fn.slick === 'function') ...`

Comment: The difference is that it first checks if the property exists in jQuery prototype, then checks if it's a function to make sure it can be called as a plugin. Your version only checks if something is defined.

Comment: @CookieMan Is this good from a performance perspective? If .slick isn't included on the page does this stop the rest of the script from running?

Comment: No, of course not :) it's just an if statement, so why would it block execution of your code. Made and example for you - http://jsfiddle.net/bhd67q6o/ you can see that alert is fired anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

You can just check if the carousel exists before calling the function like so:

```
var myCarousel = $('.my-carousel');
if (typeof myCarousel.slick !== 'undefined') {
  myCarousel.slick({speed: 330, slidesToShow: 4});
}
```

Comment: What would be the advantage of using a variable instead of CookieMan's if check?

Answer (score 1):

You can apply slick only if it is not applied, doing something like below:

```
$('.my-carousel').not('.slick-initialized').slick({
  // Your settings here.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `length` to check if it exists, for example:

`if ($('.my-element').length) {
 //do stuff
}`

Comment: This would only check if a DOM element exists, not if the script functionality is present/loaded.

Answer (score -1):

```
if($('.my-carousel').length){
   $('.my-carousel').slick({
      speed: 330,
      slidesToShow: 4,
   });
}
```

Comment: Try adding some explanation for your answer, rather than just showing the correct code. That way the questioner will learn where they went wrong.